# placing dashes in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

```js
function dashes(str) {
    str =  str.replace(/_/g,' ').replace(/\s+/g,"-").toLowerCase();
    return str;
}

//test cases
dashes("thisCakeIsDelicious");
dashes("TheBig cat was Boastful");
```

the desired output respectively are: "this-cake-is-delicious" and "the-big-cat-was-boastful". 
How do i put a space between "TheBig" without contradicting the space before "Boastful". I have tried regex particular capital letters but as you can see Big and Boastful start with B.

Answer (score 3):

This should work, but I'm not absolutely sure about the requirements so I decided to divide by word not by letter (so `LLLLie` will result in `llllie`, not `l-l-l-lie`)

`([a-z]+)([A-Z]{1})|(\s)`

Matches:

- `([a-z]+)`: 1 or more lowercase letter
- `([A-Z]{1})`: 1 uppercase letter
- `(\s+)`: one or more whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)

```js
var dasher = function(str) {
  return str
         .trim()
         .replace(/([a-z]+)([A-Z]{1})|(\s+)/g, '$1-$2')
         .toLowerCase();
}

console.log(dasher('thisCakeIsDelicious'));
console.log(dasher('TheBig cat was Boastful'));
console.log(dasher('The cakeIsA     LLLLLie'));
console.log(dasher('  JeremySpoke inClass  Today'));
```

Comment: If you use `str.trim().replace(...)` you can avoid the leading dashes and if you match with `\s+` you can avoid the extra dashes between words due to spaces.

Comment: @Jason Cust, I was thinking whitespaces are relevant but in the example OP is trying `replace(/\s+/g,"-")`, so you are right `\s+` is better. Also trimming is a good idea, I should have used that. I just found a problem, the output of `TheCakeIsALie` is `"the-cake-is-alie"`, dividing by letter is necessary in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a callback in the `replace` function

```js
function dashes(str) {
    return str.replace(/(?!^)(\s?[A-Z\s+])/g, function(x) {
     return '-' + x.trim();
    }).toLowerCase();
}

//test cases
console.log( dashes("thisCakeIsDelicious") );
console.log( dashes("TheBig cat was Boastful") );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = "thisCakeIsDelicious";
x.replace(/([a-z](?=[A-Z]))| /g, '$1-');
```

results in

`this-Cake-Is-Delicious`,

and

```
x = "TheBig cat was Boastful";
x.replace(/([a-z](?=[A-Z]))| /g, '$1-');
```

results in

`The-Big-cat-was-Boastful`